# Local Lebesgue Integrability of a Function at a Point

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-geometry

Let

$$f(z,w)=\frac1{|z|^{2a}+|w|^{2b}}$$

be a function on $\mathbb C^2$, where $a$ and $b$ are positive reals.

How may I find all $(a,b)$ with $a>0$ and $b>0$ for which $f$ is locally Lebesgue integrable at $(0,0)$?

I have deduced that both $a$ and $b$ have to be greater than or equal to $1$, but is there a more accurate result?

Comment: Have you tried spherical coordinates in $\Bbb C^2 = \Bbb R^4$? You should be able to take $|z| = r|\cos\theta|$ and $|w|=r|\sin\theta|$. I think you should have *upper* bounds on $a$ and $b$, not *lower*. I would suggest you need $\max(a,b)<2$. See if you can figure that out.